# Generation of synthetic data for Hierarchical clustering

Tags: clustering, simulation, multilevel-analysis, hierarchical-clustering, synthetic-data

I wanted to test various hierarchical clustering algorithms to check which algorithm performs best. For this, I was considering simulating some ground truth. Is the possible to generate a correlation matrix having hierarchical structures whose hierarchical components (which can be overlapping) are known? I can generate a correlation matrix having one level structures but I don't know how to generate correlation matrices having 2 level structures.

Comment: Would method such as Stochastic Kronecker Graph Generation, Multiscale Planar Graph Generation work?

Answer (score 0):

Derive them from generated data.

First generate data with the desired properties of nested structures.

Then compute the pairwise correlation matrix.

Comment: Can you please describe in detail?